# Выделить N последовательных бит как одну переменную

Tags: c, операции

Есть ли возможность на чистом СИ выделить и работать как с непрерывной последовательностью N бит. N больше 64. Максимально сколько у меня получилось выделить unsigned long long - 8 байт или double  - 10 байт. Но мне этого все равно мало. Мне нужно совместно хранить данных на ~150 бит и при помощи битовых операций доставать и класть туда значения. Если выделять как указатель на какой-то тип, то нельзя разом получить весть набор бит. При помощи битовый полей тоже не получается, ведь нельзя последовательно их передать в функцию.

Comment: [`bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) не хотите попробовать?

Comment: @Harry c++ случайно автоматом написал)) Мне нужно на чистом си. Тем более, что он работает с битами, а у меня могут быть значения по 3-14 бит

Comment: Тогда, пожалуй, массив или структура с соответствующими функциями.

Comment: У меня сейчас так и написано, данные разбиты на 3 переменных, но это совершенно не масштабируемая штука получается unsigned long long data1; //Motor(11+27=38) + height(14) + mm+ss(12)
unsigned long data2;// vel+h_vel+azimuth+horisont 9+5+9+9 = 32
unsigned char data3; // hh

Comment: А битовые поля в таком варианте сработают?

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов по идее работают, просто по заданию(по идее) не предусматривается их использование

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чем вас не устраивает что-то вроде этого?

```
typedef struct { unsigned char b[32]; } bitfield;

void zero(bitfield*b)
{
    memset(b->b,0,sizeof(*b));
}

void set(bitfield*b, int i)
{
    int idx = i/8;
    unsigned char mask = 1 << i%8;
    b->b[idx] |= mask;
}

int get(bitfield*b, int i)
{
    int idx = i/8;
    return (b->b[idx] >> i%8)&0x01;
}

int main()
{
    bitfield b;
    zero(&b);
    set(&b,15);
    set(&b,2);
    printf("%d - %d, %d - %d, %d - %d, %d - %d\n",
           2,  get(&b,2),  10,get(&b,10),
           12, get(&b,12), 15,get(&b,15));
}
```

Прочие функции написать не проблема... Масштабируется изменением константы 32 на нужную :)

Comment: Я в итоге реализовал через битовые поля для работы в программе, а затем упаковываю все в несколько элементов unsigned long long. Подтасовал данные, чтобы границы подходили под границы переменных. Как доделаю выложу код.Правда получилось кривовато: на си вторую неделю пишу, а до этого серьезно ни с одним Япом не работал

Answer (score 0):

По стути все решилось "впихиванием" полей в ull. Не очень универсально, но работает. unsigned long long *data Это массив из двух элементов

```
#define OILPressusreMask 0xF000000000000000;
#define OILTemperatureMask 0x0FE0000000000000;
#define FuelTemperatureMask 0x001FC00000000000;
#define FuelMassMask 0x00003FC000000000;
#define XMask 0x0000003FFF000000;
#define YMask 0x0000000000FFFC00;
#define mmMask 0x001FC000000003F0;
#define hhMask 0x001FC0000000000F;

#define RPMMask 0xFFF0000000000000;
#define ZMask 0x000FFFC000000000;
#define VelocityMask 0x0000003FE0000000;
#define HVelocityMask 0x000000001F000000;
#define AzimuthMask  0x0000000000FF8000;
#define HorizontMask 0x0000000000007FC0;
#define ssMask 0x000000000000003F;


struct U2
{
    // First 64 bits (8 bytes)
    unsigned long long OilPressure:4;
    unsigned long long OilTemperature:7;
    unsigned long long FuelTemperature:7;
    unsigned long long FuelMass:8;
    unsigned long long X:14;
    unsigned long long Y:14;
    unsigned long long mm:6;
    unsigned long long hh:4;
    
    // Second 64 bits (8 bytes)
    unsigned long long RPM:12;
    unsigned long long Z:14;
    unsigned long long Velocity:9;
    unsigned long long HVelocity:5;
    unsigned long long Azimuth:9;
    unsigned long long Horizont: 9;
    unsigned long long ss:6;
};

unsigned short packTo2LongLongInt( unsigned long long *data, struct U2 *aircraft)
{
    // Проверка на валидность данных. Коды ошибок подразумеваются......
    data[0] = 0; data[1] = 0;
    data[0] = aircraft->OilPressure;
    data[0] <<= 7;
    data[0] |= aircraft->OilTemperature;
    data[0] <<= 7;
    data[0] |= aircraft->FuelTemperature;
    data[0] <<= 8;
    data[0] |= aircraft->FuelMass;
    data[0] <<= 14;
    data[0] |= aircraft->X;
    data[0] <<= 14;
    data[0] |= aircraft->Y;
    data[0] <<= 6;
    data[0] |= aircraft->mm;
    data[0] <<= 4;
    data[0] |= aircraft->hh;
    
    #if defined(DEBUG)
        printf("Первые 64 бит упакованы успешно; ");
    #endif
    
    data[1] |= aircraft->RPM;
    data[1] <<= 14;
    data[1] |= aircraft->Z;
    data[1] <<= 9;
    data[1] |= aircraft->Velocity;
    data[1] <<= 5;
    data[1] |= aircraft->HVelocity;
    data[1] <<= 9;
    data[1] |= aircraft->Azimuth;
    data[1] <<= 9;
    data[1] |= aircraft->Horizont;
    data[1] <<= 6;
    data[1] |= aircraft->ss;
    
    #if defined(DEBUG)
        printf("Вторые 64 бит упакованы успешно; Упаковка завершена\n");
    #endif

    return 0;
}

unsigned short unpackFrom2LongLongInt( unsigned long long *data, struct U2 *aircraft)
{
    unsigned long long tmp;
    unsigned char i = 60;
    
    tmp = data[0] & OILPressusreMask;
    tmp >>= i;
    aircraft->OilPressure = tmp;
    
    i-=7;
    tmp = data[0] & OILTemperatureMask;
    tmp >>= i;
    aircraft->OilTemperature = tmp;
    
    i -= 7;
    tmp = data[0] & FuelTemperatureMask;
    tmp >>= i;
    aircraft->FuelTemperature = tmp;

    i -= 8;
    tmp = data[0] & FuelMassMask;
    tmp >>= i;
    aircraft->FuelMass = tmp;

    i -= 14;
    tmp = data[0] & XMask;
    tmp >>= i;
    aircraft->X = tmp;
    
    i -= 14;
    tmp = data[0] & YMask;
    tmp >>= i;
    aircraft->Y = tmp;

    i -= 6;
    tmp = data[0] & mmMask;
    tmp >>= i;
    aircraft->mm = tmp;

    i -= 4;
    tmp = data[0] & hhMask;
    tmp >>= i;
    aircraft->hh = tmp;

    i = 64-12;
    tmp = data[1] & RPMMask;
    tmp >>= i;
    aircraft->RPM = tmp;

    i -= 14;
    tmp = data[1] & ZMask;
    tmp >>= i;
    aircraft->Z = tmp;

    i -= 9;
    tmp = data[1] & VelocityMask;
    tmp >>= i;
    aircraft->Velocity = tmp;

    i -= 5;
    tmp = data[1] & HVelocityMask;
    tmp >>= i;
    aircraft->HVelocity = tmp;

    i -= 9;
    tmp = data[1] & AzimuthMask;
    tmp >>= i;
    aircraft->Azimuth = tmp;

    i -= 9;
    tmp = data[1] & HorizontMask;
    tmp >>= i;
    aircraft->Horizont = tmp;

    i -= 6;
    tmp = data[1] & ssMask;
    tmp >>= i;
    aircraft->ss = tmp;
    
    #if defined(DEBUG)
        printf("Данные распакованы\n");
    #endif

    return 0;
}
```